# Improve latency for ECS task pull time for docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have the following Dockerfile that I'm trying to figure out if I can make it smaller so the pull time from ECR is less.

```
FROM amazonlinux
COPY script.sh .
RUN yum -y install awscli git zip
CMD ["script.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
```

For context, I'm using it in an ECS task and the latency from calling runTask to actually starting the task is about 15 seconds when backed by an EC2 Task Definition and using `prefer-cached` for `ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR`. It's much much greater when backed by a Fargate Task Definition.

Any tips for either making the dockerfile smaller so the pull time is less and/or settings for the ECS task to reduce pull time?

Comment: How big is the image?  What you show doesn't seem like it should be large.  Does your _application_ use `git` at all; do you actually need to have it installed?  Similarly, does `awscli` bring along a complete Python installation you wouldn't have otherwise?

Comment: Yes, both are being used.